# Dropdown Filters and complex conditional statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, conditional-statements

I'm wondering what the cleanest way of achieving the following is:

I have a number of drop-down like so, that I'm using to filter an array.

```
<select class="fselect">
  <option value="All A types">All A types</option>
  <option value="A1">A1</option>
  <option value="A2">A2</option>
</select>
<select class="fselect">
  <option value="All B types">All B types</option>
  <option value="B1">B1</option>
  <option value="B2">B2</option>
</select>
<select class="fselect">
  <option value="All C types">All C types</option>
  <option value="C1">C1</option>
  <option value="C2">C2</option>
</select>
<select class="fselect">
  <option value="All D types">All D types</option>
  <option value="D1">D1</option>
  <option value="D2">D2</option>
</select>
```

The filters are AND OR. Such that the user can search for just A1 or D2, or they can search for A2 & B1, or All C Types & D2 or A2, B2, C1 & D2 etc. So there are increasing number of possible combinations.

I am hoping there is a way of doing this with out writing a very complex if else or switch statement as there potentially could be up to 8 different drop-downs. I am using jQuery and D3 v3 libraries.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the actual criteria you're checking against is (eg a string containing those values, array contains objects with values like `c:1`, array contains arrays of strings `['C1','A1','A2']` etc).

A possible way to get the filter requirement out.

```
var filters = []

//Monitor all dropdowns for a change
$('.fselect').change(funciton(e){
 //On change, check all of them for current state
 $('.fselect').each(function(){ // not sure if we can use $(this) ?
  $(this).val() && filters.push($(this).val()) // If you include an 'empty' value for a non-used filter then don't add to array
 })
 // filters = ['A1','All C types']
})
```

Comment: Funnily, since posting the question I went for a similar method, however I built up an object instead of an array.  Then used a condition to check whether a particular key was included for the "All C types" - if that makes sense.